# Webkit scrollbar dont works in selectbox

Tags: html, css, webkit

In webkit scrollbar doesn't work in single value select box, but works greats in multiple select box

```
CSS

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:  6px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {    
    background: none green;
    width: 6px;
}

HTML

    // Don't Works
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>



// Works perfect for this   
<select size="2">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't style it. You could use JS to make your own `select` if you really wanted.

Comment: @Qtax: Multiple select box can be styled, then why single select box can't ? If it shouldn't works, then it will be webkit bug, isn't it ?

Comment: I was just guessing, but if it's a bug or a feature is a question for the WebKit developers. ;-)

Comment: Alright, I am just sharing my thoughts... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this problem, at least not for now. You need to give a size 2 to DOM recognize that you want to see more than 2 values, CSS not supported that.

I try with "-webkit-scrollbar", "-moz-scrollbar", "-ms-scrollbar", "-o-scrollbar" and direct "scrollbar" property and I got the same result. In various browsers have various behaves. If is this part very important for you, you need to use JavaScript or jQuery **[PLUGINS](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-selectbox-plugin/)**.